# Is there any easy way to generate Interfaces for Existing classes?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have many classes.

Now i want all those classes to implement their own Interface. I can manually create interfaces by copying all method signatures to Interface.

Is there a automatic way to create them in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your source code or in package explorer or outline view, select one or more methods that are not yet implementing an interface, right-click and select "Refactor" --> "Extract interface"

Answer (score 2):

Try with right click on ImplementationClass in the package explorer or members view. Then go to Refactor(shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) -> Extract Interface . Then select methods for Interface